# Migration to staging server, pages from other site loading in

Tags: migration

I'm not really sure how this could happen, but i migrated a wordpress site to a staging server where i have many wordpress sites hosted, everything seemed to go smooth with the exception that all inner pages (not the home page) load a single page from a previous site that is currently hosted on the staging server. Both sites have completely different directories, and their own database tables, and the urls for the inner pages reflect the correct location, yet it is still loading in pages and content from this other site. I'm stumped on how to debug this, and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use some migration plugin, e. g. [Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/), because some file paths and URLs are [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) in database and it's not enough to change just `siteurl` and `home`. `Migrate DB` seamlessly do the job.